# Plotly: Set color in 3D Cone

Tags: python, colors, 3d, plotly

Using Python and Plotly, I'm trying to build a 3D vector field, for which I'd like to specify the color of each cone, using a custom vector and colorscale.

It would basically be using the following code, and adding an argument color=df["color"]

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/vortex.csv")

fig = go.Figure(data = go.Cone(
    x=df['x'],
    y=df['y'],
    z=df['z'],
    u=df['u'],
    v=df['v'],
    w=df['w'],
    colorscale='Blues',
    sizemode="absolute",
    sizeref=40))

fig.update_layout(scene=dict(aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.8),
                             camera_eye=dict(x=1.2, y=1.2, z=0.6)))

fig.show()
```

Any clue on how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Assigning colors through `color=df["color"]` would indicate that you had a number of color definitions that matched the number of rows in your dataframe. On that case you would have to specify along which axis to set the color. Correct?

Comment: yes exactly, except that I don't want to set the color using one of the "basic" axis (like x,y,z,u,v or w) but using another axis in my dataframe (which would be named "color" for convenience). Is that more clear?